# When should I split up a method into more methods?

Tags: java, methods, code-duplication

I have two similar methods for setting dimensions of a rectangle. At first, I had them combined into one longer method that set width and length. I read about keeping code modular that performs one task at a time. So split it into two methods. Also, I have separate methods for displaying messages. Am I going overboard breaking methods into smaller ones?

```
    private void userInputWidth() {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    double loopCondition = 0;
    while (loopCondition <= 0) {
        displayEnterWidth();
        double nextDouble = reader.nextDouble();
        loopCondition = nextDouble;
        if (nextDouble <= 0) {
            displayErrorMessage();
        } else {
            this.rectangleWidth = nextDouble;
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void displayEnterWidth() {
    System.out.println("Please enter the width of the rectangle ");
}
```

2nd Method

```
private void userInputLength() {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    double loopCondition = 0;
    while (loopCondition <= 0) {
        displayEnterLength();
        double nextDouble = reader.nextDouble();
        loopCondition = nextDouble;
        if (nextDouble <= 0) {
            displayErrorMessage();
        } else {
            this.rectangleLength = nextDouble;
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void displayEnterLength() {
    System.out.println("Please enter the length of the rectangle");
}
```

Comment: maybe try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Sorry,  I didn't realize this was the wrong place. I will Thanks.

Comment: If you'll notice, you've split it into two almost identical methods. Rename it to `getPositiveDouble` and have it return the double rather than set any fields, then do something like `new Rectangle(getPositiveDouble(), getPositiveDouble())`